# Default images also as user selected image functionality

Tags: taxonomy-terms, media

I have a content type with a taxonomy and based on that taxonomy, I want to have a default image to show unless the user wants to upload a different image. I'm not sure how to go about this functionality. Is there a module that should one could recommend or any suggestions?

I have used this to display taxonomy images https://www.drupal.org/node/1224916 and it works great but it doesn't give the user the option to upload their own pic.

Answer (score 0):

[Representative_image](https://www.drupal.org/project/representative_image)

> Allows you to define representative image or media fields for entities
>   like nodes, taxonomy terms and the like. These can then be used in
>   Open Graph meta tags (via tokens); or as fields in views. The media
>   module is also supported. A default image can be defined for those
>   entities without images.